# In c# are Decimal and decimal different?

Tags: c#, types

In c# if I use `decimal` (lower case 'd'), the IDE shows it in dark blue (like `int`). If I use `Decimal` (upper case 'd'), the IDE shows it in teal (like a class name). In both cases the tooltip is `struct System.Decimal`.

Is there any difference? Is one "preferred"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nope; identical. `decimal` is *defined* as an alias to `System.Decimal`, and is generally preferred, except in public method names, where you should use the proper name (`ReadDecimal`, etc) - because your callers might not be C#. This is more noticeable in `int` vs `ReadInt32`, etc.

There **certainly** isn't the Java-style boxing difference.

(of course, if you do something like declare a more-namespace-local `Decimal` that does something completely different, then there *are* differences, but that would be silly).

Comment: Thanks, Marc, and congrats on 100K!

Comment: Cheers - I'm glad I got there before xmas ;-p

Comment: Here is a great little msdn page that shows the other aliases.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287910(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Can you explain what "ReadDecimal" and "ReadInt32" are? I've never seen these Read* types.

Comment: @gWiz, for example, things like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.getint32.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getint32.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It is the same thing, Decimal is the .Net type and decimal is the c# keyword.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Decimal` it's a .NET Framework type, `decimal` is an **alias** in the C# language.

Both of them are compiled to `System.Decimal` in IL, so there is no difference.

Is exactly the same thing about `int` and `System.Int32`, `string` and `System.String` etc..

Answer (score 1):

decimal is an alias to Decimal.  They are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The dark blue is for language keywords, teal is for types. In the case of `decimal` it's a keyword representing a *type alias*.

Answer (score 1):

`decimal` is a keyword and always refers to the struct `System.Decimal` defined in base class library. `Decimal` usually means the same thing as most people have `using System;` on top of their source code. However, strictly speaking, those are not identical (you can't blindly find-and-replace them):

```
 namespace Test {
    class Decimal { }
 }

 // File2.cs
 using Test;
 class DecimalIsNotdecimal {
      void Method(decimal d) { ... }
      void Method(Decimal d) { ... } // works!
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No. They are just shortcuts.

If you hover over decimal you'll see System.Decimal. As with int and System.Int32, object and System.Object, string and System.String, double and System.Double

I prefer the decimal and string, but I really think its personal

Answer (score 0):

No, they're the same thing. One is colored as a keyword (decimal), the other is colored as a type (Decimal). The keyword is just an alias for the type.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same thing. 'deciaml' is the c# keyword for System.Decimal.

This applied to other types like string and String etc.