# Is there a meaningful difference between "Double" and "double" in .Net?

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

As regards best practices, is there a meaningful difference between using:

```
Double d;
```

and

```
double d;
```

I know best practices are fraught with contradictions, so I know the answers may vary here. I just want to know the pragmatic difference between the two.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947068/in-c-are-decimal-and-decimal-different and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915938/difference-between-decimal-and-decimal and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017282/c-difference-between-system-object-and-object. They're not *exact* duplicates, but they might as well be.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no difference. `double` is just an alias for System.Double in C#.

Note that VB.NET doesn't have the same aliasing (int for System.Int32, double for System.Double, etc), so the aliasing is just applicable to C#, not .NET as a whole.

Comment: So I take it that if one wanted to stick to using System types, Int32 would be preferred to int.

Comment: @IanC: yes, but I don't know why one would want to stick to System types. There's no particular advantage to doing so.

Comment: @Adam I suppose purely from the viewpoint that it's the base and the types are sometimes more descriptive (Int32 vs. int).

Comment: @IanC: I personally prefer 'int' and 'long', and the way Visual Studio does syntax highlighting makes those base value types (and string :)) easier to see, since the aliases don't look like normal classes.

Comment: @Adam lol you make a good point. Like I hinted at in my post, I just spent about 4 hours reading best practices. There wasn't much that was agreed on... so much for the concept.

Comment: This is wrong. `double` is not an alias for `Double`, it is an alias for `System.Double`. Which means that there is a very important difference between `double` and `Double`: `double` will *always* refer to `System.Double`, `Double` will refer to whichever `Double` happens to be in scope. Also, I believe that `double` is not part of ECMA C# or ISO C#, only Microsoft Visual C#, so it is not guaranteed to work cross-platform.

Comment: @Jorg: LukeH said what I was going to say.

Comment: `(Double)-1` interpreted as subtraction and thus produce compile error. While `(double)-1` interpreted as cast.

Comment: When disassembling Double, I found code like

    `[__DynamicallyInvokable]public const double NegativeInfinity = double.NegativeInfinity;`, and this is what has brought me here to this question. This means they cannot be the same, can they?

Answer (score 11):

No, there's no difference: [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) is a C# keyword that's an alias for the [`System.Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) type.

Comment: This is wrong. There is a very important difference between `double` and `Double`: `double` will *always* refer to `System.Double`, `Double` will refer to whichever `Double` happens to be in scope. Also, I believe that `double` is not part of ECMA C# or ISO C#, only Microsoft Visual C#, so it is not guaranteed to work cross-platform.

Comment: @Jörg: `double` is very much part of ECMA/ISO C# and *is* guaranteed to work the same on any spec-compliant implementation. As for `Double` referring to whichever `Double` is in scope: that goes without saying; note that I was careful to specifically say `System.Double` in my answer. (And anybody who declares their own `Double` type -- or `Int32` or `DateTime` or `Object` etc -- in a more local namespace should be prepared to handle the pitfalls.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually... after disassemble I found out that System.Double is a wrapper around double... So double is not a "shortcut" to System.Double.

Answer (score 1):

a bit difference here.

-You can have class,parameter,var named "Double" but if u want to name it "double" u must type @double.

-You can use Qualifier for Double but not for double.
ex

```
System.Double d; //Correct
System.double d; //incorrect. Compiler error: Identifier expected for "System." .
Double Double,@double;//Correct
double double;//incorrect ,Identifier expected for both doubles
```

the same thing for classes and parameters....also the same for String-string,Boolean-bool .....

Answer (score 0):

In C# the Double and double are the same, however Double guranateed to be the same across all .NET platforms, and as far as I remember the double IS the same on all platform, but is not guaranteed as such (despite being it de facto).

Comment: This is wrong. `double` is not an alias for `Double`, it is an alias for `System.Double`. Which means that there is a very important difference between `double` and `Double`: `double` will *always* refer to `System.Double`, `Double` will refer to whichever `Double` happens to be in scope.